# How to find a page in admin based on it's permalink

Tags: permalinks

I can visit a page that is supposed to be set to private. I know it's 'permalink' or url path. What I need to do is find the page in the admin. 
Is there a way to back trace a page based on it's permalink/url path

Comment: when you are connected in the admin, you can click on "edit page" in the admin bar.

Comment: right, however "edit page" does not show up.
Maybe this has to do with the Events section in the admin. The path to the page is /events. What is showing up is Events dropdown menu with 'add events', 'edit events' . I've made all of the pages in Events  private, but this one still shows up.

Comment: It looks like the original problem is that you no longer have an edit link on that page

Comment: @TomJNowell yes, it was because it was a 'section' or page created by the plugin. It's hard to tell because there was no 'page' related to /events . The plugin created that for the path it's pages would build off of.

Comment: The /events was not associated with any page in the section 'Pages' . This is what was very confusing. Now the plugin is disabled and all is fine.

Comment: sometimes you can find hints on the `<body>` tag. WordPress' backend also has a search-feature where you can search for the page's contents. You could also try to navigate directly to the post editor via the post/page's `id`

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. It was an events calendar plugin by Modern Tribe. This plugin was creating a 'slug' aka route as /events. 
I disabled the plugin.